# Searching for lines in a text file using python

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to search string in a txt file. Here is a sample txt file. I am working with:

```
abc
def
ghi
centre
jkl
mno
pqr
123
456
```

I am trying to match the lines in the file and if a match is found then exit the program if a match is not found then add the line to the file:

I have the following code that I am working with: my issue is it works correctly if I try to match "abc" in the file, but say if I try to match "pqr" I see my second if block is also executed.

Following is the code I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

new_data = raw_input("Enter txt:")    
file_name = "test.txt"

with open(file_name, "r") as F:
    data = F.readlines()

for num, line in enumerate(data, start=1):
    if line.strip() == new_data:
        print "exists {} {}".format(new_data, num)
        break

    if line.strip() != new_data:
        print "new data {} to be entered into line {}".format(new_data, num)

     else:
         print "break"
```

Following is the output i get if i try to match say "123" from the file:

```
Enter txt:123
new data 123 to be entered into line 1
new data 123 to be entered into line 2
new data 123 to be entered into line 3
new data 123 to be entered into line 4
new data 123 to be entered into line 5
new data 123 to be entered into line 6
new data 123 to be entered into line 7
exists 123 8
```

Comment: if a line is not found where will be the new line be inserted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC, you want the second block to execute only if the data does not exist. Well, try this:

```
for num, line in enumerate(data, start=1):
    if line.strip() == new_data:
        print "exists {} {}".format(new_data, num)
        break
else:
    print "new data {} to be entered into line {}".format(new_data, num)
```

You can take advantage of the `for...else` syntax. The `else` is executed if the loop does not `break`, i.e., if the data does not exist in the file.

Comment: nice one. for else is a bit confusing, gonna read some more about this.

Comment: @zig Indeed. It is a useful tool, and underrated too. You can look up more here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops. Also, please consider marking accepted if it works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that if the `new_data` is not found in iteration your 2nd if condition prints `new data to be entered` even if it exists in the subsequent iteration, only the the first data `abc` will give desired result as the iteration starts from there.

One good solution is already given by @COLDSPEED .

Another basic approach could be this:

```
for num, line in enumerate(data, start=1):
    if line.strip() == new_data:
        flag = 1
        print("exists {} {}".format(new_data, num))
        break
    else:
        flag = 0

if flag == 0:
    print("new data {} to be entered into line {}".format(new_data, num))
```

It will iterate through the whole data and if the `new_data` is found it will set the `flag` to be 1 and will break, else it will set the `flag` to be 0 and will print `new data to be entered`

Hope this help :)